# AngularJS directive link function not executing

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a wrapper for a jQuery element that is part of a template I'm working with.

The link method in the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Webnet/ugSsk/ is not triggered.  I can't get it to output to the console or alert.

Any suggestions?

JS:

```
angular.module('test', []).
    directive('slideToggle', function () {
        return {
            scope: false,
            replace: true,
            template: '<input type="checkbox" name="" class="slideToggle"/>',
            link: ['scope', 'element', 'attrs', function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(element);
                alert('linked');
            }],
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            }]
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div slide-toggle on="Active" off="Inactive"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for injecting arguments into your linking function like that. That's why it's not working.

Comment: you are using wrong syntax you should not be using minification syntax with link function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"all of the annotation styles are equivalent and can be used anywhere in Angular where injection is supported." -- [DI doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Since the link function doesn't support injection, you can't use the [inline annotation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inlineannotation) (or any other DI annotation style) there.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of questions/answers for the link function not working. Many of the other ones didn't do anything for me, but this one fixed it.